# Real-to-Complex FFT without redundant data?

Tags: matlab, fft, fftw

In many programming languages a real-to-complex FFT will result in a complex number on the positive side of the plain.

In Matlab a similar command produces a symmetric output occupying twice the memory. That's no fun.

I'm wondering if there are any FFT commands in Matlab that will result in the output being half the space and complex.

Something that will output this:

```
load woman;
fft_x=fftn(X);
fft_x=fft_x(1,1:end/2);%Cutting costs memory, and compute time
foo=abs(fft_x);
imagesc(log(foo));
```

Comment: @LuisMendo its a stock image in Matlab. Try the code :-)

Comment: Mine doesn't have it :-/ Anyway, if I understand correctly, you want to compute only one half/quadrant of the FFT, right?

Comment: @LuisMendo indeed as it stands Matlab's FFT must somehow duplicate the memory.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. Anyway, the FFT is _defined_ to return an _N_-point complex output from an _N_-point complex or real input

Comment: @LuisMendo Well, the FFT is an algorithm and in normal implementations real data of size N will output complex data of size N/2. Indeed, if the input were complex you would need to output N, buts its not.

Comment: DFT of a series of `N` points returns `N` points. However, if the time series is real, 2nd half of output series is just a complex conjugate reflection of 1st half. This fact is used to do FFT faster and with half the memory if you know that your input is real. What you are looking for is a function like `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d` in `FFTW` which does this. Matlab help says that it uses `FFTW` library to do FFT operations but I am unsure if it checks and chooses the appropriate function in the library for a real series. To save memory, you can do `a=fft(b); a=a(1:floor(length(a)/2)+1);`

Comment: @Guddu Indeed, but this will only do so post-facto (like the blurb posted above)

Comment: I searched around a bit, but the only thing I can find for Matlab is several variants of [rfft.m](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/rfft.html). Looking at the source, it seems to first calculate the full FFT and then throw away half, like you do. As an alternative to using Matlab, you might consider Python/Numpy. It seems that they do implement several [efficient versions for real FFTs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#real-ffts).